# PHPSpreadSheet : Site can't be reach

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, xlsx, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

Try to export xlsx file using PhpSpreadSheet in CodeIgniter 3.
When i run the url, it shows This site can't be reach. Web might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

**Controller**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
                
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

function generateLR(){
                    // create file name
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="result.xlsx');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
  $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
  $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
  $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
  $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet); 
  $writer->save('php://output');
}
```

But if i try to save locally `$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');`. The output save successfully in project folder.

Also try using IOFactory but the result is the same : web is temporary down

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
                
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

function generateLR(){
                    // create file name
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="result.xlsx');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
  $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
  $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
  $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
  $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet,'Xlsx');
  $writer->save('php://output');
}
```

**Error image**
[image]
Is there any env problem ?

Comment: Have you checked what the error log has to say?

Comment: if i see error log, there is no error, If i check access_log it shows   "GET /generateLR HTTP/1.1" 500,   "-" 408 - @CBroe

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. The problem is the permission of `sys_get_temp_dir()`. My temp folder is unaccessable by default in Macbook. After change the permission. Excel can be created in localhost

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).